# Installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 3.0.0 Prompting "Untrusted Publisher"

Tags: asp.net-core-3.0, ef-core-3.0

While performing:
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -Version 3.0.0

To the end of installation, I am getting following prompt:

```
Executing script file 'C:\Users\phirkabh\.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\3.0.0\tools\init.ps1'
Do you want to run software from this untrusted publisher?
File C:\Users\phirkabh\.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\3.0.0\tools\init.ps1 is
published by CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US 
and is not trusted on your system. Only run scripts from trusted publishers.
[V] Never run  [D] Do not run  [R] Run once  [A] Always run  [?] Help (default is "D"):
```

I chose D (since that is default). but then the `Scaffold-DbContext` is not working. Reinstalling (after removing) it is not helping. What seems to be going wrong here? Is this a EF Core problem or something else?

Comment: Most people use `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` to always trust downloaded scripts which have been signed

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I already have it that way. Get `Get-ExecutionPolicy` returns `RemoteSigned` on Powershell prompt.